# Can Windows Containers be run on top of Kubernetes in a local development environment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a windows 10 PC and want to run asp.net windows containers on top of a single node Kubernetes for testing before deploying to the cloud, so is this feasible?.

Answer (score 0):

yes, windows 10 natively supports docker. you should be able to run windows containers.
use minikube for run single node kubernetes cluster and then deploy your windows container

Comment: I'm not able to run windows containers in minikube, is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the above answer and your question I will try to  dispel your doubts.

Minikube is a tool that helps to run Kubernetes locally. Minikube enables to run single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a Virtual Machine (VM) on your laptop. You can read about minikube here: [`minikube`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/).

Windows 10 **supports** docker. You can run asp.net windows containers on top of a Kubernetes cluster.

So assuming you have already running Kubernetes cluster you don't have to care about minikube. Just deploy your windows container on top of it. You can read about it here: [`windows-setup`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/windows/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Minikube is just tool for automatic deployment of Kubernetes cluster. We cannot run Windows containers on top of minikube. Writting "... Just deploy your windows container on top of it. ...  " I meant to deploy windows containers on top of Kubernetes cluster.